# How to find the value in a node using a double pointer when that node is passed through a function and accepted as a double pointer?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

guys I am desperately trying to learn how to manipulate linked lists and I am having a hard time. I can't understand most of the tutorials online and they all don't seem intuitive to me. I have successfully tried to append a node at the beginning of a linked list using a double pointer, but the nature of this double pointer isn't behaving like I thought it would. Please refer to my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{ 
public:
    int value;
    node* next;
};
void push2front(node** ptr, int n) //a node pointer is now equal to the address of the head node
{
    cout<<"ptr: "<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<"*ptr: "<<*ptr<<endl;
    node* new_node = new node(); //create a new head node
    new_node->value = n;
    new_node->next = *ptr;
    *ptr = new_node;
    return;
}

int main() {
    
    node* head = new node();
    node* second = new node();
    node* third = new node();
    int input = 54;
    head->value = 1; 
    head -> next = second; 
    second->value = 2;
    second->next = third;
    third->value = 3;
    third->next = NULL;
    cout<<"head: "<<head<<endl;//address of the data member value of head
    cout<<"&head->value: "<<&head->value<<endl;//address of the value data member of node head
    cout<<"&head: "<<&head<<endl;//address of the head node itself
    cout<<"head->next: "<<head->next<<endl;//address of the next node after head
    cout<<second<<" "; //address of the data member of 2nd node
    cout<<&second->value<<" ";//address of the data member of 2nd node
    cout<<&second<<endl;//address of the 2nd node itself
    push2front(&head, input); //pass the address of the actual head node as well as the user inputted integer
    while (head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->value<<" ";
        head = head->next;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output of this program is as follows:

```
head: 0x921520
&head->value: 0x921520
&head: 0x7bfe08
head->next: 0x921540
0x921540 0x921540 0x7bfe00
ptr: 0x7bfe08
*ptr: 0x921520
54 1 2 3
```

I placed a lot of cout in the program to see what happens as the program runs. Everything is fine and DANDY until the moment the I call the push2front() function. Here are my questions:

1.) Am I correct when I think that **&head->value or** simply **head** is the address of the value data member of the head node? Because based on what my cout shows, this seems to be the case.

2.) So does that mean that **&head** is the ACTUAL address of the node?

3.) I always thought that the next part of any node points to the ACTUAL address of the node next to it? So essentially I thought that
**head->next == &second**? But it seems that (according to the cout) nodes apparently point to the address of the value data member in
another node?

4.) If **head: 0x91520 == *ptr: 0x91520*** why does **head->value** work and *****ptr->value**** doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `head` contains the address of the first node. That is, the address of the beginning of the memory occupied by that node. That is also the address of the `value` member of that node, because that node and its `value` member start at the same place.
2. `head` is a pointer, which is a variable. `&head` is the address of that pointer. **Pointing to a thing is not the same as pointing to a variable that contains the thing's address.**
3. Yes, if the list is constructed correctly, the `next` part of any node points to the next node, which is to say it contains the actual address of the next node. So `head->next` == `second`, which is the address of the second node, and also of the second node's `value` member. It is *not* the case that `head-next` == `&second`, because `second` is a pointer that is not part of the list at all.
4. `(*ptr)->value` works; `*ptr->value` doesn't. The pointer operator (`->`) takes precedence over the dereference operator (*), so when you try to use `*ptr->value`, the compiler sees that as `*(ptr->value)` and complains *"what do you mean, `ptr->value`? `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer to a thing that has members."*

Comment: OMGGG. Thank you soo much. I just realized this myself when I examined the part of the code: "node* head = new node()"....Now I understand that the 'head' which is a pointer itself that contains the address to a node structure. And that &head is the ACTUAL address of that head pointer!! THANK YOU SOO MUCH.

Comment: Also thank you for giving a very clear answer to number 4!!! I NEVER knew that -> takes precedence in this case and I don't even know how to begin to search that in google. My teacher NEVER covered this stuff. I knew there was a way to use *ptr to access a node's data and next members...I just didn't know how...but your explanation why was very intuitive and I understand much better now. Thank you!!!!